# Removing first character from string results in segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, argv

Im attempting to create a program that reads in a file that contains the letters [a-z]. I then replace a with 1, e with 2, i with 3, o with 4 and u with 5. I run the program with the commmand

> ./tr aeiou 12345 < data.txt //No space between the < and data.txt

My code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(argv[3], "r");
    char input[100];
    fscanf(fp, "%[^\n]", input);
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    if(argv[3][0] == '<') {
        (*(argv[3]))++; //SEGFAULT
    }
    while(input[a] != '\0') {
        if(input[a] == argv[1][b]) {
            input[a] = argv[2][b];
            ++b;
        }
        ++a;
    }
    printf("%s", input);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

If i run the program with

> ./tr aeiou 12345 data.txt //Notice no <

Then it works fine but it gives me segmentation fault when i run it with the <.  Why is this? From my understanding it shouldn't take up any more memory by just shifting the pointer one character to the right.

Is there an easier way to do this? Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: I think you will find that `argv[3]` is null. Use a debugger to confirm. You should check `argc` and remember C starts arrays with an index of zero.

Comment: @EdHeal you are correct but `argv[0] = ./tr`

Comment: Where does the command line get separated between the stuff that the shell uses and you program uses? Just check the value of `argc`

Comment: @EdHeal So why does it work if i dont type the `<` before `data.txt`?

Comment: @JackWilliams Why do you want to pass the third argument with a `<`?

Comment: @CrakC This is an assignment and that is how we need to do it

Comment: `<` is redirection for input. that's *not* a program argument.

Comment: @JackWilliams I am asking about your purpose. What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I believe its `<<`

Comment: @CrakC: I don't really care what you *believe* in ;)

Comment: @JackWilliams: at this point it's impossible to give a proper answer as we have no idea what you want to do.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Thanks I figured it out though. I was just unaware what < did exactly. I didnt know it was redirecting the input from data.txt

Comment: You really should check `argc > 3` before using `argv[3]` ; doing so would have alerted you to the problem. Also , `fopen` should be follwed by a test if `NULL` was returned; passing null pointer to file reading functions causes udnefined behaviour

Comment: If you run with `<`, the file’s contents are piped to `stdin`.  The classic approach programs such as `more` use is to check `argc > 1` and, if so, open `argv[1]`, if not, read standard input.

Comment: By the way, your call to `fscanf()` has a buffer overrun.  Try either `fscanf(f, "%99[^\n]", input)` or `fgets()` followed by `sscanf()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that regardless whether you have a space or not between `<` and `data.txt`, that `<` will be interpreted by the shell as the file input operator and thus will not be passed into the program. I have written the following snippet in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    printf("%s \n", argv[i]);
  }
}
```

Which just prints out all the arguments. Calling `./test.out aeiou 12345` gives:

```
./test.out
aeiou
12345
```

as expected. But calling `./test.out aeiou 12345 <6789` will result in the terminal complaining that there is no such file 6789. I then created a file called 6789 containing the text "6789". But it won't have any effects. The output remains:

```
./test.out
aeiou
12345
```

The problem in your code is exactly that the `argv[3]` is null. `data.txt` is passed into the input but not in the form of `argv`.

Comment: "data.txt is passed into the input but not in the form of argv" -  only if the program *consumes* input from `stdin`, which is where the text from that file will be redirected to. OP's program does not use `stdin`.